# Get optimal value of variable gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I have a question about obtaining values ​​from the objective function. My objective function consists of 2 parts, `objective = X + Y`. `X = grb.quicksum(Z_vars[i,j,k] * TC_distmatrix[i,j] for i in set_N for j in set_N for k in set_K` and `Y = grb.quicksum(X_vars[q,r,p] * TC_distmatrix2[q,r] for q in set_M for r in set_M for p in set_P)` are both calculated using a summation of other variables. Now, I would like to know what the individual value of `X` and `Y` are. However, I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you please include some of your code to get a better understanding of how and what you're using?

Answer (score 2):

`quicksum` returns a `LinExpr` object. You can call `getValue()` on it to get its (current) solution value. (https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_lex_getvalue.html)

So for your example:

```
sol_x = X.getValue()
sol_y = Y.getValue()
```